# How to do a regex replace on a JavaScript ArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, regex, arraybuffer

How do I do a regular expression replacement on an `ArrayBuffer` in JavaScript?

From what I can tell `.replace` in JavaScript expects a `String` as the input and doesn't support `ArrayBuffer`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

My thought would be to convert the `ArrayBuffer` into a `String` and then do the replace, then convert it back to an `ArrayBuffer` - will there be any data loss if this is done?

Comment: Does the `ArrayBuffer` contain unrestricted data? That is: is every byte combination possible?

Comment: That's correct, the `ArrayBuffer` is an HTTP POST's raw body.

Answer (score -3):

With the information that the buffer contains arbitrary data, than: yes, there is a possibility of data loss.

A JavaScript string is encoded in 16-bit Unicode, so this simplified example

```
("asd\u0000asd").length
```

returns `7` despite having 8 bytes all over (it could even return 3 in browsers other than Firefox). You can work around that with a bit of care, of course, but I would deem it safer (and probably easier) to do the replacing earlier if possible or do it by hand if the regex is not too complicated.

I think this is one of the places where the old saying

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems. 
>   -- Jamie Zawinski

holds a tiny bit of truth ;-)